# Change a text-shadow style in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using multiple sliders to get the rgba values for a text-shadow.
But I can't make it assign those values to change the text-shadow style.

```
<h1 id="myHeader" style ="text-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #FF00FF">Hello World!</h1>
```

My JavaScript code looks like this:

```
<script>        
        function changeColor() 
        {
            var op = document.getElementById('Opacity').value;
            var red = document.getElementById('Rosu').value;
            var green = document.getElementById('Albastru').value;
            var blue = document.getElementById('Verde').value;'
            var color = 'rgba(' + red +',' + blue + ',' + green + ',' + op/100 + ')';

            document.getElementById('myHeader').style = 'text-shadow: 5px 5px 3px ' + color;

        }

        document.getElementById('Opacity').addEventListener('input', changeColor); 
        document.getElementById('Rosu').addEventListener('input', changeColor); 
        document.getElementById('Albastru').addEventListener('input', changeColor); 
        document.getElementById('Verde').addEventListener('input', changeColor); 


</script>
```

Comment: There is a dangling `'` at the end of this line `var blue = document.getElementById('Verde').value;'`
And where is the rest of the HTML ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct, but you have a single quote to remove after `document.getElementById('Verde').value;`

You can also use `style.textShadow`, here is an example:

```js
var color="#00ff00";
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('myHeader').style.textShadow = '5px 5px 30px ' + color;
};
```

```html
<h1 id="myHeader" style ="text-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #FF00FF">Hello World!</h1>
<button id='btn'>Change shadow</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely functional code (not optimized, though):

```
<h1 id="myHeader" style="text-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #FF00FF">Hello World!</h1>

<p>
    <label for="opacity">Opacity</label>
    <input type="text" name="opacity" id="opacity" placeholder="Opacity" value="1">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="rosu">Rosu</label>
    <input type="text" name="rosu" id="rosu" placeholder="Rosu" value="1">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="albastru">Albastru</label>
    <input type="text" name="albastru" id="albastru" placeholder="Albastru" value="1">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="verde">Verde</label>
    <input type="text" name="verde" id="verde" placeholder="Verde" value="1">
</p>

<script>
    function changeColor() {
        var op = document.getElementById('opacity').value;
        var red = document.getElementById('rosu').value;
        var green = document.getElementById('albastru').value;
        var blue = document.getElementById('verde').value;
        var color = 'rgba(' + red + ',' + blue + ',' + green + ',' + op / 100 + ')';

        document.getElementById('myHeader').style.textShadow = '5px 5px 3px ' + color;
    }

    document.getElementById('opacity').addEventListener('input', changeColor);
    document.getElementById('rosu').addEventListener('input', changeColor);
    document.getElementById('albastru').addEventListener('input', changeColor);
    document.getElementById('verde').addEventListener('input', changeColor);
</script>
```

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/laruiss/yghw75mz/) on jsfiddle

Answer (score -1):

Need to use `camelCase` instead of `kebab-case` if you are updating CSS attribute using javascript.

Use `document.getElementById('myHeader').style.textShadow = '5px 5px 3px ' + color;`